# Match list of strings with column and return corresponding column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

This is my dataframe df3:
[image]

My Template files are named like:
`AdDape CBS Index Template 6.3.xlsx`

`AdDape Midlife Index Template 5.3.xlsx`

`CausalIQ Index Template 5.xlsx`

I'm iterating over my excel files and then in a nested loop I'm iterating over its excel sheets. I have saved the file in df2 it has several columns and 3 sheets like below:
The file's sheet look like this (df2): [image]

I want to get Grouping value. If my actual filename matches with the df3.filename and then match it's sheet with the `df3.sheetname` and then get the corresponding Grouping.

The code I'm using is:

```
for fname in TemplateFileList:
excel = pd.ExcelFile(fname)

     for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
     print("\nSelected sheet: ", sheet)

        df2 = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=sheet)
        print('\n',sheet,df2.head(5))

        m=df3['Filename'].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, fname, limit=10)).all()
        if m:
            print(m)
```

In simple language, what I want is:
if fname is similar to df3[filename]
then
if fname's sheetname or df2's sheet is similar to df3[sheetname]
then
return the corresponding df3[costgroup]

If you observe the actual filename is not exactly same to filenames in df3, this is the actual problem, also actual sheetnames are different with the sheetnames in df3.
I know about fuzzy matching, but I'm not sure how to use. I used it like this:

```
        m=df3['Filename'].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, fname, limit=10)).all()
        if m:
            print(m)
```

this is giving me output like this:

> [('A', 60), ('d', 60), ('D', 60), ('a', 60), ('t', 60), ('S', 60), ('S', 60), ('a', 60), ('y', 60), ('d', 60)]

Comment: the way your code block is formatted here, your `for fname in TemplateFileList:` isn't doing anything, because the code beneath it isn't indented. Is that how you have it formatted/indented in your actual code?

Comment: I have indented properly in the actual code, and the loop is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think what you generally want here is to use `merge()`, which will merge together two dataframes to give all the columns of both.

Your df2 will need columns for filename and sheetname. It looks like you might have to do a little work to get them into the same format as what you have in df3. Once you have that, though, merge will get you the `grouping` column as well.

```py
df_merged = df1.merge(df2
    ,how='left' #this will give all rows from df1, even if they don't have matches in df2
    ,on=['Filename','Sheetname'] # this assumes that the columns titles are the same in both dfs
    )
```

Comment: After I create column in df2 for filename and sheetname, and merge both df2 and df3, how do I then match them? because the actual filename and sheetname are not exactly same with the ones stored in df3.

Comment: You'll need the strings to match exactly for a merge. In your case, one way to do it would be to add some more columns to each table for those proper mappings. For example, On `df2`, maybe you have a column for `filename` like you do, and then another new column of `filename_short` that just takes the first two words from the sheetname, or something like that. And another column on `df3` like `filename_match' that would be `AdDape CBS` or whatever your match actually is/should be. I'm about to head out for ~8 days, so can't help more, sorry, but there is a lot of SO about custom columns. gluck

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, can't understand. Appreciate it though, thanks!